# why does my app treat a get route as a resource id and then map to the wrong controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want a route/view/controller action called `pending` to display all `:foo` resources requested by a current user. This view would  be functionally identical to `index`, and differs only in that it shows resources that are both created by the current user *and* pending.

My routes.rb:

```
resources :foo
get 'foo/pending', controller: 'foo', action: 'pending'
```

FooController.rb

```
def pending
 @foo = current_user.foo.unapproved
end
```

Even though I'm declaring the controller and action in my get route, `pending` gets used as the `:id` param, and then the whole thing gets routed to the FooController's `show` action. Which I don't even have written. Why? Thanks!

Comment: Try moving the get above the resources line.  Or else you can include inside a a resource block as a collection method.

Answer (score 1):

resources :foo will generate all CRUD routes for foo controller which also includes

```
get /foo/:id
```

And routes in Rails are evaluated top down so you need to put

```
get 'foo/pending'
```

Before

```
resources :foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a route for pending action inside resource :foo like this:

```
resources :foo do
  collection do
    get :pending
  end
end
```